# Webview2 Approach Does not work looking for alternative options

Tags: webview2

I have **WPF** Application which have a code of initializing Internet Explorer using **SHdocVw** and since IE getting decommissioned would like to navigate it directly to Edge.

My code now :

```
Internet Explorer Ie = new Internet Explorer();
Ie.Navigate2(URL,Empty,PostDataText,headers)
```

I tried webview2 approach but it needs runtime installer in machine or beta version of edge.
Is there any other way of achieving this?

Answer (score 0):

You can automate the Edge browser with [WebDriver](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webdriver-chromium/?tabs=c-sharp) or [Puppeteer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/puppeteer/). They provide a different set of capabilities than the old Internet Explorer COM objects or the Edge WebView2 but if all you want to do is open a browser window and navigate with post data, that should work.